# If I send an encrypted message using Apple Mail, are the attachments also encrypted?

Tags: macos, email, encryption, apple-mail

A while ago, I'd tested this by sending myself an email with a file attached, then opening it in a web-based client. What I saw was a blank message with a single `smime.p7m` attachment. I assumed this must contain the body of the message and the attachment, both encrypted.

Recently, though, I got a nasty surprise from iMessage—it apparently *doesn't* encrypt files you send. This lead me to be suspicious about pretty much everything that transfers files and claims to be secure.

Are attachments sent using Mail *really* encrypted with the body of the message, or are they just sent insecurely alongside it?

Comment: This depends on the client: what are you using?

Comment: @Matteo It does? O.o I would think it would be a standard that all clients follow. I use Apple Mail, in any case.

Comment: @EricDANNIELOU The [tag:mac] tag is for hardware; [tag:osx] is for Mac software. See the tag wikis. :)

Comment: iMessage claims to be secure?

Comment: @DanielBeck _With end-to-end encryption, your messages stay safe and private._ https://www.apple.com/osx/apps/#messages